# How to use $GLOBALS to share variables across php files?

Tags: php, arrays, global

I have a file, `index.php` that produces a link to a page that I want my user to *only* be able to access if some `$var == True`.

I want to be able to do this through the $GLOBALS array, since my $_SESSION array is already being filled with instances of a specific class I want to manipulate further on.

My `index.php` page:

```
<?php

    $var = True;

    $GLOBALS["var"];

    echo "<p><a href='next.php'>Click to go to next page</a></p>";

?>
```

My `next.php` page:

```
<?php

        if($GLOBALS["var"] == False)
            exit("You do not have access to this page!");
        else
            echo "<p>You have access!</p>";

?>
```

Currently, `next.php` is echoing the exit text. Am I accessing/assigning to the $GLOBALS array correctly? Or am I not using it properly?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
So I've tried some of the suggestions here. This is my new `index.php`:

```
<?php

    $GLOBALS["var"] = True;

    echo "<p><a href='next.php'>Click to go to next page</a></p>";

?>
```

My `next.php`:

```
<?php

    if($GLOBALS["var"] == False)
        exit("You do not have access to this page!");
    else
        echo "<p>You have access!</p>";

?>
```

However, I'm still running into the same issue where the exit statement is being printed.

Comment: `$GLOBALS["var"];` <--- what's this?

Comment: I thought that was how to assign to the $GLOBALS array - I was going off of [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php). I'm guessing I'm way off?

Comment: you assign using `=` operator. `variable = value` <- this is the generic form of assignment. You've only provided left part and didn't assign anything to it.

Comment: Remove `$GLOBALS["var"];` line from the first file.

Comment: @Aziz Saleh: actually OP needs to assign a value there, not remove it.

Comment: @zerkms The value is already assigned by `$var = True;`, read up on using `$GLOBALS` here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Aziz Saleh: you're *assuming* that that code runs in a global scope, which is not guaranteed.

Comment: so I don't need to use $GLOBALS at all in `index.php`?

Comment: @user3773076: you do. Assign a value there as I've already told you.

Comment: I would suggest that you look up php sessions and cookies and common ways to provide page-level access.

Comment: I see what is happening, I was thinking this was an include. What everyone else is saying is correct, use sessions to carry the value over.

Comment: I've adjusted my code like @zerkms suggested, but I'm still running into the same issue.

Comment: @user3773076 is there any reason you're not using session for this? **You can create new session variables.** [For example, **`$_SESSION['my_new_variable'] = FALSE;`**](http://br2.php.net/session_start)

Comment: @user3773076: you need to explain the relation between `index.php` and `next.php` then. Does one includes the other?

Comment: @Prix Well, I'm currently using session to store instances of a class, as this is part of a bigger project. So my session array is populated with objects named "item1", "item2", etc. I just thought it would be simpler to store my $var value in a separate superglobal.

Comment: @zerkms The files are in the same directory, but neither includes the other. Is that my problem here?

Comment: @user3773076: global variables are not persisted across the requests, but only within single php run.

Comment: @user3773076 you're making NO sense at all, you don't mind storing item1, item2 but you do mind storing to your session whether the user is or not logged in/have access to a specific part of the site?

Comment: @zerkms Ah, okay. I'll rethink my implementation. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's much better to use sessions for this, since they are more secure and exist for this purpose. The approach I would recommend, is starting a new separate session array.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['newSession']['access'] = true;
```

Then to access it use the same key/value.

Comment: Down voting without stating a reason is counterproductive.

Comment: That works, although I was looking for a solution that used $GLOBALS. Thank you for the suggestion though, and if I had enough rep to upvote I would!

Comment: Just figured out a way to use this method and preserve the objects I had in my session array, and it works! Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, it comes in handy creating different session arrays :)